# R, rounding, ceiling and floors

Tags: r, rounding

Suppose that one has a bunch of data returned from pnorm(), such that you've got numbers between .0003ish and .9999ish.

```
numbers     <- round(rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 100, sd = 15))
percentiles <- pnorm(numbers, mean = 100, sd = 15)*100
```

And then further suppose that one is interested in rounding the percentiles such that .0003 or whatevs will come out to 1 (so ceiling()), but 99.999 will come out to 99 (so floor()).

I guess what I'm looking for is round() that somehow brilliantly knows to reverse it in the extreme cases, but as far as I know, no such thing exists.  Am I going to have to ugly it up with an if statement?  Is there a better method of handling such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `round` and force things into `1` or `99` at the extremities using `pmin` and `pmax`:

```
pmax(1, pmin(99, round(percentiles)))
```

Comment: That's a great solution.

In such a case, would it be better to use pmax() and pmin() before hand?  It's hard to tell if it matters.

    `test1 <- pmax(1, pmin(99, round(percentiles)))`
    `test2 <- round(pmax(1, pmin(99, percentiles)))`
    `all.equal(test1, test2)`

Seems to suggest that at least in this case it's the same.  I mean, if I'm even doing that right!

Comment: It doesn't matter because each of the three functions is run on the full vector. What could have made a difference is something like `pmax(1L, pmin(99L, as.numeric(round(percentiles))))` if the `pmax` and `pmin` functions were faster at processing `integer` than `numeric` but as I tested, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: That makes total sense.  Thanks!  :D